# Display element in angular based on condition in array of objects

Tags: angularjs

I have the following element.

```
<div> My element</div>
```

and the following object:

```
$scope.myObject = {'life_log' : [{status: 'ALIVE'},{status: 'DEAD'}]}
```

How can I display the element ONLY if all status is ALIVE.

I know how to use ng-show on a variable but what about a condition like this?

Comment: In general you'd probably use ng-if but there could be a different way depending on how you are using myObject.life_log?  In an ng-repeat where you'll iterate through all of the objects in the collection?  Some other way?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create a function that loops through your array and checks if all the statuses are 'ALIVE'. Or just use a reduce method on the array:

```
$scope.allStatusesAreAlive = $scope.myObject.life_log.reduce(function(a, b) {
    if (a === false) return false;
    if (b.status === 'DEAD') return false;
    return true;
}, true);
```

Then you can display your element if $scope.allStatusesAreAlive is true:

```
<div ng-if="allStatusesAreAlive"> My element</div>
```

Comment: Awesome.  I tried using a function but myobject is always empty.  I'm guessing becasue the view is built before.  How do I fix that?

Comment: If you're making an AJAX request to get the data for myObject, then you'll need to tell angular to update the view. You can do that by putting your code inside a $timeout (that triggers the digest cycle that rerenders the view. $timeout calls $rootScope.$digest, which triggers the digest cycle). You'll have to inject the $timeout service in your controller and use it like this $timeout(function() { update myObject here });

Comment: Also filtering for 'ALIVE' and comparing the length would work and I think that's easier to read. Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/zeuzzp6w/). The reduce is also a nice way of detecting it. I think your code can be optimized a bit. Please have a look at the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
angular.forEach($scope.myObject.life_log, function(item){
    if(item.status !=='ALIVE'){
        $scope.isAlive = false;
        break;
    }else{
        $scope.isAlive = true;
    }
});
```

then in your html

```
<div data-ng-if="isAlive">My element</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link

https://plnkr.co/edit/ermeKk1dBX8D54pL7vHQ?p=preview

angular code:

```
  $scope.myObject = {'life_log' : [{status: 'ALIVE'},{status: 'DEAD'}]}
             $scope.val=true;
              for(i=0;i<$scope.myObject.life_log.length;i++){

                if($scope.myObject.life_log[i].status != "ALIVE")
                $scope.val=false;
              }
```

html code:

```
<div ng-show="val">My element</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// This is here to make it configurable
$scope.keys = Object.keys($scope.myObject);

// In this case you have the "life_log" key
$scope.keys.forEach(k => {
   $scope.myObject[k].forEach((d) => {
      // our object here is myObject["life_log"];
      // obj is a temp array to check the amount of statuses that are dead 
      var obj = [];
      d["allAlive"] = d.status.forEach( s =>{
         if(s == 'DEAD'){
            obj.push("Dead");
         }
      });
      if(obj.length > 0){
         d.allAlive = false
      }else{
         d.allAlive = true;
      }
   });
});

   <div ng-if="myObject[o].allAlive>
      ALL ALIVE
   </div>
```